# How do I extract unique values from SQL?

Tags: sql

For example suppose I have the following table

```
user_id, score
1,5
1,4
2,9
3,7
3,6
3,15
4,8
4,11
```

I want a query that returns user_id 2 because it is the only user_id that is not repeated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id FROM table GROUP BY(user_id) HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id 
from tableName
group by user_id 
having count(*)  = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING (COUNT(user_id)=1)
```